# Forcing Reload of View when returning from FlipSideView of Utility Application

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa

I've got a Utility Application for iPhone 3.1.3. I have my main view loading fine. I flip over to the flipside view of the utility app and change some settings. How can I call the code I've currently got in `viewDidLoad` in the main view to refresh it, as settings have changed?

Do I create a public method and call it from the viewDidUnload method of the flipside view? Do I call `viewDidLoad` directly? What's the best way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, you should never call `viewDidLoad` directly. It probably won't cause any problems, but it's best to leave a method like that to be called by the underlying API only. Just move out some of the view initialization into a new method like `configureViewForSettings` or something along those lines.

The best approach would be to use delegation. This is most suitable when you need to send back some sort of data or notification to a 'parent' view. Create a new protocol `MySettingsViewDelegate` with a method like `settingsViewChangedSettings:(MySettingsView *)settingsView`. Then on your settings view controller add a `id<MySettingsViewDelegate> delegate` property.

When the settings change call the delegate method like this:

```
[self.delegate settingsViewChangedSettings:self];
```

And in your main view controller, when you create/display the settings view, set yourself to be the delegate

```
mySettingsView.delegate = self;
/* Display the settings view */
```

Then somewhere:

```
- (void)settingsViewChangedSettings:(MySettingsView *)settingsView {
    /* Settings changed, refresh your view */
    [self configureViewForSettings];
}
```